# PHP, HTML, Javascript - Create an interactive dropdown menu from a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, foreach

I am making a voting page where users are able to vote on several polls which have different answers depending on the category. To keep it simple:

### Code explanation

I have 2 foreach loops: the first one iterates over all the polls, and prints them out. The second one iterates over all the availabe answers for the poll. Multiple answers are received from the category_id. The answers are printed out under each poll. The way it is currently displayed is that each poll with its corresponding answers are printed out under eachother, kind of like a list.

### What i want to have

I want to have a dropdown menu, which displays all the available polls upon being clicked. When a poll is clicked it must show the poll itself and the corresponding answers.

I am pretty new to this and I hope that this is not too much too ask for, if so I hope that you can point me in a right direction at least.

### Code

```
<!-- Voting form --> 
<h3> Pollpagina </h3>
<?php
    //prepare statement to select all polls
    $get_polls = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM polls');
    $get_polls->execute();
    $all_polls = $get_polls->fetchAll();
    //treat every poll as an individual poll
    foreach($all_polls as $single_poll) {
?>  
        <!-- Create a form for each poll, with the corresponding answers as radio buttons -->
        <form method="post" action="">
            <div class="poll">
<?php
                //get textual poll and its corresponding id and category
                $poll_id = $single_poll['id'];
                $poll = $single_poll['poll'];
                $category = $single_poll['category_id'];
                //echo each poll
                echo $poll, "<br>";
                //prepare statement for getting all the answers from a specific category
                $category_answers = $db->prepare('SELECT answer FROM answers WHERE category_id = ?');
                $category_answers->bindValue(1, $category, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $category_answers->execute();
                $all_answers = $category_answers->fetchAll();
                //create a radio button for each answer
                foreach($all_answers as $single_array_answer) {
                    $single_answer = array_shift($single_array_answer);
?>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="<?php print_r($single_answer); ?>"> <?php print_r($single_answer); ?>  <br>
<?php
                }
?>
                <!-- If a vote has been submitted, the value tag will send the corresponding poll id -->
                <button type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php print_r($poll_id); ?>"</button>Submit
            </div>
        </form>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Use PHP to access data on the Server. JavaScript to alter code on the Client. Learn AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

you can combine some php and javacript.

## to show polls :

```
<select id="dropdown">
   <?php
     echo "<option value='$pollId'>$pollName</option>";
   ?>
</select>
```

## to show all poll answers use jquery:

```
$("#dropdown").on("change",function){
  <?php
   /*
      print all poll answers here 
   */
?>;
}
```